# Title is written vertically instead of horizontally HTML

Tags: html

In essence the  above the text writes each word below each other instead of horizontally.
Text is just words from Wikipedia.

[image: I cut this out of the main code]

Here is the code:

```css
{
  display:flex;  
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;

}

.location1
{
  width: 1900px;
  height: 320px;
  border: 3px solid #82817d;
}
```

```html
  <div class="location1">
    <div class="p">
    <img src="Night11.png" alt="Blur" style="width:320px;height:320px;">    

    <h1> Test Test Test </h1>
    <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;The great spotted woodpecker (Dendrocopos major) is a medium-sized woodpecker with pied black and white plumage and a red patch on the lower belly. Males and young birds also have red markings on the neck or head. This species is found across Eurasia and parts of North Africa, in all types of woodlands. Some individuals have a tendency to wander, leading to the recent 
        The great spotted woodpecker (Dendrocopos major) is a medium-sized woodpecker with pied black and white plumage and a red patch on the lower belly. Males and young birds also have red markings on the neck or head. This species is found across Eurasia and parts of North Africa, in all types of woodlands. Some individuals have a tendency to wander, leading to the recent 
        The great spotted woodpecker (Dendrocopos major) is a medium-sized woodpecker with pied black and white plumage and a red patch on the lower belly. Males and young birds also have red markings on the neck or head. This species is found across Eurasia and parts of North Africa, in all types of woodlands. Some individuals have a tendency to wander, leading to the recent 
        The great spotted woodpecker (Dendrocopos major) is a medium-sized woodpecker with pied black and white plumage and a red patch on the lower belly. Males and young birds also have red markings on the neck or head. This species is found across Eurasia and parts of North Africa, in all types of woodlands. Some individuals have a tendency to wander, leading to the recent 
    </p></div> </div>
```

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: This seems to be a CSS problem. Share you CSS.

Comment: Try to use https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_images_side_by_side.asp

Comment: HI Dakotah, to be able to help you out, we need to see what's happening. Post a [reprex] including all the code that leads to the problem...

Comment: It looks like you set `display: flex` to the `.p` container, which makes all its direct children stack horizontally and shrink to fit together in the container width. You probably need an extra wrapper for the heading and the paragraph to make them behave as regular blocks again.

Comment: @RenevanderLende This [link](http://www.cssdesk.com/EH7Um) This is most minimal I could make it, this is the issue with the Image frame

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn Is there a way to use a wrapper, because I used it like a div class and div ID without avail

Comment: @DakotahHutchinson ID or class for the wrapper is not needed, just a `<div>` around the text content should be enough (http://www.cssdesk.com/89cf6)

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn Okay so I put the divs in [here](http://www.cssdesk.com/EH7Um) but it doesn't seems to affect them, only the display on .p affects them

Comment: It should be a single `div` containing both heading and paragraph, not separate wrapping around each of them. The main idea is that `.p` block should have only two direct children, one being the image and another being everything else. All direct children of the flex container (element with `display: flex` or `inline-flex`) will stack horizontally, but their own content will be laid out as usual.

Comment: It works now, Thank you the answer